# Disaster recovery/Server Migration for databases that are permanently in Standby

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've got an old 2005 server where 8/12 of the databases are in `Standby/Read-Only`. This server has 81 jobs, many of them with unique id's for names. One of these jobs is called `Replicate`, and it calls a .cmd file every 30 minutes. The .cmd calls a .pl that looks like some sort of home-brewed log shipping.

I'd like to bump the databases out of standby so I can back them up properly, but I'm worried it will break everything.

To make matters worse, while the server is a VM, there is (according to the VM admins) a problem with the drives where it sits, making it impossible to back up. They are worried that the server could die at any time, so we *have* to do something.

The databases are relatively small - I *may* be able to get in and out in the 30 minutes between the `Replicate` job. There's no test environment, though, so I can't find out easily.

We do have vendor support, but they don't seem to be very good. Am I better off just handing them the keys?

**Question:** How would you go about backing up this server without knocking it down in the process?

Comment: Just do a native sql server full backup - `backup database dbname to disk = 'your disk\dbname.bak' with init` .. since you are on 2005, backup compression (was an EE feature - need to check .. do not recall).

Comment: can't back up a DB in standby though, right?

Comment: No .. you cant backup a standby db .. but readonly - yes. when you said `Standby/Read-Only` I assumed you have a mix of standby and readonly dbs :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are at least the following methods here for your consideration.

1. BCP (Bulk Copy) out each table and then script out the database and then you can recreate a new db using these data and scripts.
2. You can temporarily take the db offline (by detaching the db) and then copy the MDF file and/or LDF file. You can use the file copy to reattach it to another db.
3. If you want doing online, you can simply create an SSIS package to dump the data (of course, your destination db should be created the same way as the source db, which you can script it out)

Comment: Oh man. I wrote a script that will back up & restore a whole database using .txt files, giggling to myself the whole time, because I thought it was really stupid. Time to go dust it off...